# Why does Vue3 need source element in the audio element?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

can play mp3. Vue 2 version. but doesn't work with Vue3.

```html
<template>
  <audio
    src="../file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"
    controls
  ></audio>
</template>
```

It needs to be done this way with Vue3.

```html
<template>
  <audio controls>
    <source src="../assets/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
</template>
```

Why do I need a source element?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a source element, if you only provide a single media resources for the `<audio>` element.

`<audio>` and `<source>` are not Vue-specific elements.

> The `<source>` HTML element specifies multiple media resources for the `<picture>`, the `<audio>` element, or the `<video>` element ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source))

```html
<template>
  <audio
    controls
    src="../assets/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3">
  </audio>
</template>
```